# How to set array value as javascript function closure in php?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, heredoc

I'm trying to implement my own renderer for handsontable plugin in my php project.
So the set of params for plugin is prepared as php array:

```
$options = [
    'data' => $orders,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'data' => 'email',
            'renderer' =>

// Heredoc goes here
<<<JAVASCRIPT
function(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
JAVASCRIPT

        ],
        ...
    ]
];
```

Then it is passed to plugin as argument:

```
$this->registerJs('hot = new Handsontable("mydiv", ' . json_encode($options) . ')');
```

So when html is rendered I see this:

```
hot = new Handsontable("mydiv", {
    'data': ...,
    'columns': [
        {
            'data': 'email',
            // Here is the problem!
            'renderer': 'function(value) { \n\r console.log(value) \n\r }'
        },
        ...
    ]
});
```

The problem is I cannot pass this function as closure, only as a text in quotes.

Is it possible?

Comment: A here-doc is always a string. There's no way to encode functions in JSON.

Comment: @Barmar should I define function before and pass it's name as param?

Comment: Something like that, but there's no easy way to get that with `json_encode()`. Can you put multiple statements in `registerJs()`?

Comment: @Barmar actually there are some flags passed: JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK

Comment: @Barmar registerJs is Yii2 View function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't encode a function in JSON. The thing to do is assign the object to a variable so you can add the function as a separate step in the Javascript.

```
$options = [
    'data' => $orders,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'data' => 'email'
        ],
        ...
    ]
];

$jsFunc = <<<JAVASCRIPT
function(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
JAVASCRIPT;

$this->registerJs('var options = ' . json_encode($options) '; options.columns[0].renderer = ' . $jsFunc . '; hot = new Handsontable("mydiv", options);');
```